# c++ search for a specific file (text.ini) and list the results, including path in a listbox

Tags: c++, file, search, directory

I'm pretty new to C++.  What i'm trying to do is search the drives for specific file and list them all (including the path in a listbox).

I have tried to do a few things like the one below but i just cannot get it to work.

1. I'm not sure where to put the name of the file in that code.
2. How can i search mutiple drives if they have c: and d:

Thanks!

```
int main()
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA file;
    HANDLE search_handle=FindFirstFile("C:\\*",&file);
    if (search_handle)
    {
        do
        {
            std::wcout << file.cFileName << std::endl;
        }while(FindNextFile(search_handle,&file));
        FindClose(search_handle);

    }

}
```

Comment: I highly recommend learning C or C++ and picking one of those languages to develop your program.  Mixing the languages adds more complexity to your program.  Please update your language tags accordingly.  BTW, `std::wcout` is not supported in the C language.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Any suggestion in regards to the code?

Comment: Although I have worked in the Windows file arena, it has been some time and I'm not doing that right now, so I'm not offering any comments.  Also, due to my work schedule, I can't copy your code and debug it.

Comment: ok i got it working using findFirstFile and findNextFile.  Only thing now is how can i make it search all the local disks? Thanks!

Comment: @Andy, did you try `FindFirstVolumeW()` and `FindNextVolumeW()`?